# What is different between Data from String and Image in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, string, uiimage, nsdata

In Swift, We can convert String to Data, and convert from UIImage to Data also. So, what is different between two Data? Can Anyone help. Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data - Converting to data basically allows you to treat with the String or UIImage in terms of the constituent bytes that make up these objects.

Answer (score 2):

To quote Apple's documentation:

> The `Data` value type allows simple byte buffers to take on the behavior of Foundation objects.

Essentially it provides a byte buffer representation of Foundation objects, which allows you to access/manipulate the object's bytes in memory.

You can read more about the `Data` structure on Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But Can we convert from String to Image and from Image to String?

Comment: @Cu'iBap yes but you need to first get your UIImage data representation (HEIC, JPEC, PNG, etc) then you can convert the Data to base64 encoded string. Note that Data it is just a sequence of bytes (UInt8 0-255). It can be anything. Every file on your computer is just a bunch of bytes. How you will interpret that depends on its URL path extension (or its UTI type identifier). If you don't know the type of data which it is written it is simply useless.